# Creating an infix operator

Tags: haskell, infix-notation, non-exhaustive-patterns

I've run into a little problem i can't seem to solve, been at it for a few hours now to no avail.

I've defined a datatype, Hand.

```
data Hand = Empty | Add Card Hand
        deriving (Eq, Show)
```

And another type i'm using:

```
data Card = Card { rank :: Rank, suit :: Suit }
        deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I'm trying to create an infix operator which will add two hands and return a third one.

```
(<+) :: Hand -> Hand -> Hand
(<+) (Add c1 h1) (empty) = (Add c1 h1)
(<+) hand1 (Add c2 hand2) = (Add c2 (hand1 <+ hand2))
```

When i run a quickcheck test on this to see wether it's associative or not i get an error after a few times. The error says:

```
BlackJack.hs:(71,1)-(72,53): Non-exhaustive patterns in function <+
```

The three arguments it returns to me are empty (Always this one as the first one) and then a large hand as a second and the third argument. For example: [image: Image of error.]
Also, quickchest test looks something like `((hand1 <+ hand2) <+ hand3) == (hand1 <+ (hand2 <+ hand3))`.

I'm guessing i've got not enough cases to handle every possible scenario? I just can't figure out what's gone wrong. :(

Please no direct solutions, hints will do!

**Edit:** Did as a helpful commenter suggested and added a case for when two hands are empty, which returns the empty hand. All works well now. :) 
And to clear up confusion, i had declared what a empty hand is earlier. Empty and empty are two defferent things in my code, and i used them 'correctly'. :)

Comment: `empty /= Empty`. Also, your left parameter can be empty and you don't match for that.

Comment: You don't handle any case in which both hands are `Empty`

Comment: Instead of posting an image copy the *text* and paste it into the question in a code block. It's actually 1) easier to read 2) we can copy and paste the code that it's contained. In this case it doesn't matter, but it *does* matter in other circumstances.  (also: titles shouldn't contains tags,  and error messages are better formatted in code blocks).

Comment: If you had compiled with `-Wall` the compiler would have told you that you have non exhaustive patterns. Moral of the story: always use `-Wall`.